# RTK Query Not Following Redirect

Tags: redux, rtk-query

I have a tunnel that I'm using for my auth provider that forwards requests to their api. It's necessary for the dev environment. Now if I use axios to send requests through the tunnel, the results work just fine, all 200 status codes. But I wanted to migrate a few of the requests over to redux and so I created a few endpoints in my api slice. When I tried calling the api though with the RTK hooks, I'm getting a 303 status code. In my base query I tried adding {redirect: 'follow'}, but that didn't change anything, still the 303 error. Here is my api slice

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

export const apiSlice = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'api',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URI,
        credentials: 'include',
        redirect: 'follow',
    }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({}),
})
```

and here is the endpoint causing the error:

```
import { apiSlice } from '@api/apiSlice'



export const orySlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getSettingsFlow: builder.query({
            async queryFn(arg, _queryApi, _extraOptions, fetchWithBQ) {
                const oryBaseUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_ORY_API_URI
                let result
                if (arg.flowId) {
                    result = await fetchWithBQ({
                        url: `${oryBaseUrl}/self-service/settings/flows/?id=${arg.flowId}`,
                    })
                } else {
                    result = await fetchWithBQ({
                        url: `${oryBaseUrl}/self-service/settings/browser`,
                    })
                }
                return result.data ? { data: result } : { error: result.error }
            }
        })
    }),
})

export const {
    useLazyGetSettingsFlowQuery,
} = orySlice
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a custom base query that uses axios, and then used queryFn  property for the endpoint.

```
        getSettingsFlow: builder.query({
            async queryFn(arg) {
                const oryBaseUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_ORY_API_URI
                let result
                let refetch = false
                if (arg.flowId) {
                    result = await axiosBaseQuery({
                        url: `${oryBaseUrl}/self-service/settings/flows/?id=${arg.flowId}`,
                        method: 'GET',
                    })
                    if (result.status === 410) {
                        refetch = true
                    }
                }

                if (refetch || !arg.flowId) {
                    result = await axiosBaseQuery({
                        url: `${oryBaseUrl}/self-service/settings/browser`,
                        method: 'GET',
                    })
                }
                return result.data ? { data: result.data } : { error: result.error }
            }
        })
```